# C#: Path.Combine not giving full path

Tags: c#

Below code not giving full path, what could be the reason?

`var X = Path.Combine( Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROGRAMFILES(X86)"), "/ABC/XYZ.exe");`

**Output**: /ABC/XYZ.exe

**Expected**: C:/Program Files (x86)/ABC/XYZ.exe

Comment: that variable is only available if your app is running as a 64bit app otherwise use regular PROGRAMFILES

Comment: even my issue is same

Comment: Try getting rid of the leading `/` in `/ABC/XYZ.exe`.  It’s currently an absolute path; make it a relative path.

Comment: have you tried printing just the first part of the path in isolation ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second argument to `Path.Combine` ("/ABC/XYZ.exe") starts with a slash, which is putting you back at the root. Remove this leading slash and you should get the output you are after.

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROGRAMFILES(X86)"), "ABC/XYZ.exe")
```

From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If path2 does not include a root (for example, if path2 does not start with a separator character or a drive specification), the result is a concatenation of the two paths, with an intervening separator character. If path2 includes a root, path2 is returned.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following code instead:

```
var programFilesPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
var X = Path.Combine( programFilesPath, "ABC/XYZ.exe" );
```

Notice I removed the leading '/' character. When it is present, the `Path.Combine` will use the second path instead of combination as it takes it as root. `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles` always refers to the `ProgramFiles (x86)` version of Program Files.

Comment: but still `X = /ABC/XYZ.exe`

Comment: still the problem is same

Comment: I have updated my answer. You need to remove the '/' character at the beginning of the second string